Why does a system call crashes on second iteration of cycle while succeed on first?
I faced this problem in the below C++ program
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> args;

void SetUpSlave(std::string path) {
    std::vector<char*> args_ptrs;
    args_ptrs.reserve(args.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); ++i) {
        args_ptrs.push_back(args[i].data());
    }
    execv(path.data(), args_ptrs.data());
    cerr << "Errno value: " << errno << endl;
    assert(false);
}

int main() {
    int status;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        args = { "/usr/bin/echo", "MESSAGE" };
        pid_t slave_pid = fork();
        if (slave_pid) {
            assert(waitpid(slave_pid, &status, 0) != -1);
        } else {
            SetUpSlave("/usr/bin/echo");
        }
        std::string(17, 'a');
    }
    return 0;
}



Somehow this code fails with output:
MESSAGE
Errno value: 14
test: /tmp/tmp.9dU24JfFL4/main.cpp:17: void SetUpSlave(std::string): Assertion `false' failed.

This problem occurred on Ubuntu 24.04 with g++ 13.2.0.
if I change std::string(17, 'a'); to std::string(16, 'a');, then the error disappears.
Also helps changing args_ptrs.reserve(args.size()); to args_ptrs.reserve(args.size() + 2);

Because you don't check fork() result that can be -1.

See Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? and Why using namespace std is bad practice.

@3CxEZiVlQ in this code it's not checked, but I checked it right now and it's actually not -1.

execv expects a null-terminated array of null-terminated strings, meaning the last const char* element must be NULL. Otherwise it has no way to tell how many arguments there are.
std::string::c_str() would be more idiomatic for C code but as @john pointed out, data() is also null-terminated.
void SetUpSlave(std::string path) {
    std::vector<const char*> args_ptrs;
    args_ptrs.reserve(args.size() + 1); // +1 for nullptr 
    for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); ++i) {
        args_ptrs.push_back(args[i].c_str()()); // Null-terminated string
    }
    args_ptrs.push_back(nullptr); // Add null terminator to the array
    
    execv(path.data(), args_ptrs.data());
    cerr << "Errno value: " << errno << endl;
    assert(false);
}


string::data() is guaranteed to be null terminated from C++11, and highly likely to be null terminated before that too.

@john You are right, my mistake, thanks for the correction.
